# EZTwain - where is it writing the file too?

Tags: vb.net, scanning

A colleague left the job assuring everyone he had checked-in the latest version of the source code of an old scanning application (VB.NET Win Forms).  He hadn't.  The compiled version works perfectly but the checked-in version does not.  After de-compiling the working version with Red Gate's .NET Reflector we get the code below.

The application uses [EZTwain](http://www.eztwain.com/pub/eztp/EZTwain_User_Guide.pdf).  I am expecting the line `EZTwain.DibWritePage(num2)` to write the file to the `path` specified.  It doesn't.  Everything else works fine.

Where is the file?  DocLocation = "C:\Scanner\" and that folder exists.

```
Private Sub cmdScan_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdScan.Click
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    If (Me.SearchList.ListBoxReference.Length = 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a Reference before proceeding.", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Me.SearchList.Focus()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Else
        Dim num As Integer = 1
        Dim str As String = Me.SearchList.ListBoxReference.Replace("/", "-")
        Dim path As String = (My.Settings.DocLocation & str & "_v0001.tif")
        Do While True
            Dim strArray As String()
            If Not File.Exists(path) Then
                Try
                    EZTwain.OrganizationLicense(My.Settings.EZTwainOrganisation, My.Settings.EZTwainKey)
                    EZTwain.SetHideUI(False)
                    EZTwain.SetFileAppendFlag(False)
                    EZTwain.SetJpegQuality(&H4B)
                    EZTwain.SetTiffCompression(2, 7)
                    EZTwain.SetResolution(CInt(Me.cboDefaultResolution.SelectedItem))
                    If EZTwain.OpenDefaultSource Then
                        EZTwain.SetXferCount(-1)
                        EZTwain.SetAutoScan(True)
                        EZTwain.SetMultiTransfer(True)
                        EZTwain.BeginMultipageFile(path)
                        Do While True
                            Dim num2 As System.IntPtr = EZTwain.Acquire(Me.Handle)
                            If (num2 <> 0) Then
                                EZTwain.DibWritePage(num2)
                                EZTwain.DIB_Free(num2)
                                If (EZTwain.State >= 6) Then
                                    Continue Do
                                End If
                            End If
                            EZTwain.CloseSource()
                            EZTwain.EndMultipageFile()
                            Exit Do
                        Loop
                    End If
                    If (EZTwain.LastErrorCode <> 0) Then
                        EZTwain.ReportLastError("Unable to scan.")
                        File.Delete(path)
                        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
                    Else
                        If (File.Exists(path) And (FileSystem.FileLen(path) < 20)) Then
                            File.Delete(path)
                        ElseIf File.Exists(path) Then
                            Dim num3 As Double = (CDbl(FileSystem.FileLen(path)) / 1000000)
                            Try
                                strArray = New String() {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path), " (", num3.ToString("N3"), "Mb ", Convert.ToString(File.GetCreationTime(path)), ")"}
                                Me.lstDocuments.Items.Add(String.Concat(strArray))
                                Me.lstDocuments.Sorted = True
                                If My.Settings.ImagePreview Then
                                    Interaction.Shell((My.Settings.ImageViewer & " " & path), AppWinStyle.MaximizedFocus, False, -1)
                                End If
                                Me.lstDocuments.SelectedIndex = -1
                            Catch exception3 As Exception
                                Dim ex As Exception = exception3
                                CompilerServices.ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex)
                                Dim exception2 As Exception = ex
                                MessageBox.Show(("An error occurred while saving the file." & ChrW(13) & ChrW(10) & "Error - " & exception2.Message & ChrW(13) & ChrW(10) & "Please Try again."), Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
                                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
                                CompilerServices.ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
                                Exit Do
                            End Try
                        End If
                        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
                    End If
                Catch exception1 As Exception
                    Dim ex As Exception = exception1
                    CompilerServices.ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex)
                    Dim exception As Exception = ex
                    MessageBox.Show(("An error occurred while scanning the image." & ChrW(13) & ChrW(10) & "Error - " & exception.Message & ChrW(13) & ChrW(10) & "Please Try again."), Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
                    If File.Exists(path) Then
                        File.Delete(path)
                    End If
                    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
                    CompilerServices.ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
                End Try
                Exit Do
            End If
            num += 1
            strArray = New String() {My.Settings.DocLocation, str, "_v", num.ToString.PadLeft(4, "0"c), ".tif"}
            path = String.Concat(strArray)
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The path is defined here

```
 (My.Settings.DocLocation & str & "_v0001.tif")
```

and then given to the twain software here:

```
  EZTwain.BeginMultipageFile(path)
```

If you look at the compiled application's exe.config there should be a node defined as DocLocation giving the path to be used.

Comment: Doh! Forgot the ref. to the path is given.  DocLocation is defined in the app.config but the file isn't written there.  For clarity the DocLocation = "C:\scanner\" and that folder exists.

Comment: Original post edited to remove my erroneous mention of path not being supplied to EZTwain.  Clearly it is, nevertheless it still doesn't write to that path.  Thanks for spotting my error.

Comment: Removal of the down vote would be appreciated as this is a real-world problem and the original post has been edited to better describe the issue.

Comment: TBH, I don't see anything immediately obvious as wrong. have you stepped through it with the debugger?

Comment: Debugged and can't find anything wrong myself.  Path is as given but no file is written to disk.  I've a hunch it may be the interaction between TWAIN and the particular scanner driver I'm testing with (which came bundled with a new Fujitsu SP 1120).  Fujitsu are usually good when it comes to TWAIN so that hunch is unlikely to be valid.  I will be testing with an older, higher spec., Fujitsu device to be sure.